# Powershell: Create folder with '.' in the name

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am trying to create a folder that has '.' in the name using following command in Powershell without success:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "MyDocuments.pictures"
```

It silently fails, without throwing any exception or error.
I also have administrator privileges when running this command.

Comment: I could not reproduce this when I tried; do you get an error if you add `-ErrorAction Stop`?

Comment: How did you conclude it didn't work? Does a subsequent call to `Get-Item "MyDocuments.pictures"` throw an error?

Comment: do you have write permission in that folder?

Comment: How about giving the full path to that folder? Are you searching for it in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Path is not the Folder itself but the Folder in which you want to create your folder. This works for me:

```
$DirName = "MyDocuments.pictures"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\temp" -Name $DirName | Out-Null
Get-Item "C:\temp\$DirName"
```